# What is the industrial equivalent of a dimmer switch for resistive heaters?

Tags: heat, current-limiting, pid-controller

**Question:** What is the industrial, solid-state equivalent of a dimmer switch?

**Background:** I am building a PID box, and I want to limit the current draw on a 1.5 kW resistive heating element to simplify the controls. In the past, I have used a PWM controlled SSR, but this still requires the controls to be able to handle the full 12 A draw. Is there a component that does what I am describing? I don't need to be able to adjust it after it is set.

**Goal:** limit peak current draw.

Comment: Temperature PID controllers -- nice self-tuning ones -- run a bit more than $100.  Are you sure its worth your time to build one?

Comment: http://www.omega.com/pptst/CN142.html  -- and if this is what omega charges, you can find something similar for maybe $70 elsewhere

Comment: What is your present config?  All you need maybe is a thermostat and contact switch controlled trigger to a Triac with ON OFF control.  what tolerance is needed for temp error and rate of change from heater will determine temp. ripple with a 0.5C thermostat resolution.

Comment: If you want efficiently to have pretty constant current you could use Buck controller? This is the pretty common on low voltages. I guess it could be used also for your problem. But I am not sure you need it. You have heating element and those work fine with PWM. They would be "overload" in the ON cycle (if I understood you) but as long you switch fast enough (and keep duty cycle low enough) it would not fail. It fails only if temperature of the heater goes too high.

Comment: The time constants involved in temperature control are generally pretty long.  Most of the controller's I've seen just use on/off control on a macro scale, not 60Hz line frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.5 kW ... 12 A ... I am trying to find a way to limit the current requirement of the heater so that the on state is ~5 A.

[image]

*Figure 1. Phase angle control. By delaying the turn-on point in the mains half-cycle power can be reduced from close to 100% to close to 0%.*

You have correctly realised that even with phase-angle control set to a point to reduce the current you will need a device rated for the full current. For example, if the phase control of Figure 1 is set to 50% or 6 A in your application the peak current switched remains at the same value as a full-wave 12 A. There will be a small reduction at 5 A.

You have been caught out by one of the earliest pieces of electrical legislation - Ohm's law. Since \$ I = \frac{V}{R} \$ your only to options to reduce I are to (1) reduce V or (2) increase R.

Solutions:

1. Use a higher rated SSR. It won't complicate the controls any further but might may take a little more space. You need a non-zero-cross type but now need to time your trigger pulses relative to the mains zero-cross. This may complicate things too much for you.
2. Use a transformer to reduce the voltage to 5/12 of the original. A simple SSR will work then.
3. Change the heater to a 600 W, 120 V unit.
4. Use your full 12 A but with the required duty cycle to get the power you require.

[image]

*Figure 3. Proportional on-off time control. Note that step size is one half-cycle minimum. This can make the response seem coarse if the repeat time is short.*

Since most heater applications have some thermal inertia a slow (relative to mains frequency) on-off control can give the required average output power.

Comment: You are the first commentator to fully understand my problem. Peak current. 12 A isn't a problem, but when you add more PID/heaters  in the same box and they all decided to switch on at the same time, that's a lot of current. I will have to go with option 2. Again, thank you for your thorough response.

Comment: Thanks. With on-off control (rather than dimmer control) as I have suggested you can arrange for the heaters to alternate thus keeping the current to 12 A max per pair. You even have the luxury of a little off time between each transition. Update your question with more details if you wish and post a comment here to alert me.

Answer (score 1):

There are industrial heater controllers. They usually have a PID or PI controller built in as well as a temperature display, temperature setting buttons and a temperature sensor input. If you want your use your own PID controller, you need a control amplifier, variable voltage control or power control rated for the voltage and current that you need. You should be able to find something suitable if you search using terms like those mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your prompts.  I have done a fair share of Googling now, and honestly, I am still having trouble finding these things. I keep getting results for (1) PID heater controllers made to operate a device that actually handles the power (but haven't found this second device), or (2) AC power supplies. Is this just not something people do?

Comment: SCR Power Control is probably the search term to use. You may get results for both AC and DC output, but for a heater, it doesn't much matter which you use.

Comment: "Proportional power controller" seems like it might be the best term. These items provide a variable AC or DC output that is proportional to a 0-10V, 4-20mA or other input signal.